# Error convert data type varchar to numeric when using a case statement order by

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server.  I have a table called `ReviewWebsite` with a column `Answer VARCHAR(1000) NULLABLE`.

This query runs perfectly:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(4,2),Answer) AS Rating FROM ReviewWebsite WHERE ReviewQuestionId = 2) AS tbl ORDER BY Rating DESC;
```

But this query causes an error:

```
DECLARE @SortDir VARCHAR(1000) = 'ASC';
DECLARE @SortCol VARCHAR(1000) = 'Rating';

SELECT * FROM (SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(4,2),Answer) AS Rating FROM ReviewWebsite WHERE ReviewQuestionId = 2) AS tbl
ORDER BY
    CASE
    WHEN @SortDir <> 'ASC' THEN ''
    WHEN @SortCol = 'Rating' THEN tbl.Rating
    END ASC,
    CASE
    WHEN @SortDir <> 'DESC' THEN ''
    WHEN @SortCol = 'Rating' THEN tbl.Rating
    END DESC;
```

With the error being:

```
Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 4
Error converting data type varchar to numeric.
```

What did I do wrong and how do I correct this?

Extra notes incase it matters - the query above is actually part of a bigger set of queries that are `UNION` together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing data types being returned by your `CASE` statement.

Per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types) a `CASE` statement:

> Returns the highest precedence type from the set of types in result_expressions and the optional else_result_expression.

Your statement is returning either `''`, a character data type, or a Rating value that is a `decimal`. If we check the [data type precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) list we see that `decimal` has precedence:

> 1 user-defined data types (highest)
>
> 2 sql_variant
>
> 3 xml
>
> ...
>
> 12 decimal
>
> ...
>
> 25 nvarchar (including nvarchar(max) )
>
> 26 nchar
>
> 27 varchar (including varchar(max) )
>
> 28 char

So you get the error

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 4
> Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Because SQL Server can't convert `''` to a numeric data type. You could try converting Rating to a varchar, or returning 0 or NULL instead of a string.

Based on your snippet, it might be easier to do this with dynamic SQL to construct the `ORDER BY` clause more cleanly.

Comment: Oooh i see....  I replaced all instances of `THEN ''` with `THEN 0`.  Thanks for catching that